# How to change color of paintComponent from another class

Tags: java, swing, colors, paintcomponent

I have an oval component on a panel in OvalShape.java that I would like to change the color of

```
public class OvalShape extends JPanel {
private int diameter = 100;
private Color myColor = Color.RED;

//create the actual panel
public OvalShape() {
    Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
    size.width = 300;
    size.height= 300;
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredSoftBevelBorder());
}

public void setMyColor(Color theColor) {
    this.myColor = theColor;
}

//create the oval
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillOval(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
    g.setColor(myColor);
}

//method for setting the diameter
public void setDiameter(int newDiameter) { //method to create diameter
    //if diam invalid set to 10
    diameter = (newDiameter >=0 ? newDiameter : 10);
    repaint(); //repaint panel
}
```

}

from OvalPanel.java I want to be able to change the color. Here is what that class looks like

```
public class OvalPanel extends JPanel {
public int diameter = 100; //default diameter of the oval
public JSlider diamSlider;
public JLabel diamLabel;
public OvalShape ovalShape;

public OvalPanel() {

    Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
    size.width = 500;
    setPreferredSize(size);

    //create components
    diamSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 300, 100);
    diamSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
    diamSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(100);
    diamSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(25);
    diamSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    diamSlider.setPaintLabels(true);

    diamLabel = new JLabel("Diameter = " + diameter);
    ovalShape = new OvalShape();
    ovalShape.setDiameter(diamSlider.getValue());
    ovalShape.setMyColor(Color.RED);

    //set listeners
    diamSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            diamLabel.setText("Diameter = " + diamSlider.getValue());
            ovalShape.setDiameter(diamSlider.getValue());
        }
    });


    //set layout
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    ////////first row////////
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(ovalShape, gbc);

    ////////second row////////
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    add(diamSlider, gbc);

    ////////third row////////
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    add(diamLabel, gbc);
}
```

but I don't really understand why this isn't working. The oval just comes out black. I have tried to apply the same theory that I did when creating the diameter slider as I am able to change the diameter of the oval using the slider in OvalPanel.java

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g.fillOval(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
g.setColor(myColor);
```

You need to set the color BEFORE you paint the oval.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I know have the below `g.setColor(myColor); 


super.paintComponent(g);


g.fillOval(0, 0, diameter, diameter);`

Comment: @LukeBray No, the above is not correct. The super.paintComponent() should be the first statement. Its job is to paint the background of the panel. Then you change the color and do your custom painting.